# Why do I need an explicit return when a Promise is returned?

Tags: javascript, promise, return

I'm trying to understand this piece of code:

```
//Get local text file data
function getText() {
  fetch('test.txt')
    .then(function(res){
      return res.text(); //Question HERE!
    })
    .then(function(data) {
      console.log(data);
      document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = data;
    })
    .catch(function(err){
      console.log(err);
    });
}
```

In particular, I can't understand why I need to have return res.text(). Isn't the method text() returning already a Promise? So why do I need to explicitly return there?
My idea is to get the Promise from the first .then and treat the latter witht the second then. But withoout that return, my variable data is logged as undefined.

Comment: How else would you get the `res.text()` promise "out" if you don't return it?

Comment: Good point. I'm just not used to Promises and JS in general. I still can't see how returning that res.text() can be used in the following .then.

Comment: That's how `.then` works: It returns a promise (A) that resolves to the return value of its callback. If that return value is another promise (B) then A will be resolved with the same value as B is resolved. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then#Return_value

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`res.data()` does return a promise, but if you simply leave it there it will be function existing in its own scope with no purpose. When you return that function, you can chain it to the next `then`.

Update - Expanding on the `res.text()`

res.text() is doing the following inside:

```js
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  // Do something with your data and then
  resolve(data)
})
```

Now, when you call `res.text()`, that is the value you receive back: a `Promise` object in the `pending` state. The `Promise` object is what you chain `then` and `catch` to. But if you don't `return` the Promise, your function will create a Promise **but return nothing**. So when you use `.then`, it tries to connect to `undefined`, which is the value function returned.

So, essentially what you're doing there is:

```js
function getText() {
  fetch('test.txt')
    .then(function(res){
      const promise = res.text();
      return promise;
    })
    .then(function(data) {
      console.log(data);
      document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = data;
    })
    .catch(function(err){
      console.log(err);
    });
}
```

Comment: I perfectly understood the first part of your answer (thanks!). I still have some doubts about the last part. I can't see how the next "then" can have the value previously returned. I think this short hand notation is confusing me somhow. Would you have any clarificartion about it?

Comment: I've edited the answer and tried to expand on what's happening. In the end, I isolated `res.text()` and `return` into their own lines. I hope this helps!